# How to join 3 tables in order to get a result with two tables alternating

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have 3 tables, foo bar and baz, where bar and baz having different additional informations about the datasets in foo. Is there a way to join these 3 tables together, so that in every output row is either a `(foo <join> bar)` or `(foo <join> baz)` dataset?

Say, I have the following tables:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+----+-------+
| id | foo   |
+----+-------+
|  1 | start |
|  2 | mid   |
|  3 | end   |
+----+-------+

mysql> select * from bar;
+----+-----+-----------+
| id | bid | bar       |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 |   1 | bar-start |
|  2 |   2 | bar-mid   |
|  3 |   3 | bar-end   |
+----+-----+-----------+

mysql> select * from baz;
+----+-----+-------------+
| id | bid | baz         |
+----+-----+-------------+
|  1 |   1 | baz-start-1 |
|  1 |   2 | baz-start-2 |
|  1 |   3 | baz-start-3 |
|  2 |   4 | baz-mid-1   |
|  2 |   5 | baz-mid-2   |
|  2 |   6 | baz-mid-3   |
|  3 |   7 | baz-end-1   |
|  3 |   8 | baz-end-2   |
|  3 |   9 | baz-end-3   |
+----+-----+-------------+
```

I can extract all the information with a query which joins those tables together via

```
mysql> select * from foo join bar join baz on foo.id = bar.id and foo.id=baz.id;
+----+-------+----+-----+-----------+----+-----+-------------+
| id | foo   | id | bid | bar       | id | bid | baz         |
+----+-------+----+-----+-----------+----+-----+-------------+
|  1 | start |  1 |   1 | bar-start |  1 |   1 | baz-start-1 |
|  1 | start |  1 |   1 | bar-start |  1 |   2 | baz-start-2 |
|  1 | start |  1 |   1 | bar-start |  1 |   3 | baz-start-3 |
|  2 | mid   |  2 |   2 | bar-mid   |  2 |   4 | baz-mid-1   |
|  2 | mid   |  2 |   2 | bar-mid   |  2 |   5 | baz-mid-2   |
|  2 | mid   |  2 |   2 | bar-mid   |  2 |   6 | baz-mid-3   |
|  3 | end   |  3 |   3 | bar-end   |  3 |   7 | baz-end-1   |
|  3 | end   |  3 |   3 | bar-end   |  3 |   8 | baz-end-2   |
|  3 | end   |  3 |   3 | bar-end   |  3 |   9 | baz-end-3   |
+----+-------+----+-----+-----------+----+-----+-------------+
```

But I would like to get an output like the following table, since that would make the code in the application consuming the data much simpler:

```
+----+-------+------+------+-----------+------+------+-------------+
| id | foo   | id   | bid  | bar       | id   | bid  | baz         |
+----+-------+------+------+-----------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | start |  1   |   1  | bar-start | NULL | NULL | NULL        |
|  1 | start | NULL | NULL |           |  1   |   1  | baz-start-1 |
|  1 | start | NULL | NULL |           |  1   |   2  | baz-start-2 |
|  1 | start | NULL | NULL |           |  1   |   3  | baz-start-3 |
|  2 | mid   |  2   |   2  | bar-mid   | NULL | NULL | NULL        |
|  2 | mid   | NULL | NULL |           |  2   |   4  | baz-mid-1   |
|  2 | mid   | NULL | NULL |           |  2   |   5  | baz-mid-2   |
|  2 | mid   | NULL | NULL |           |  2   |   6  | baz-mid-3   |
|  3 | end   |  3   |   3  | bar-end   | NULL | NULL | NULL        |
|  3 | end   | NULL | NULL |           |  3   |   7  | baz-end-1   |
|  3 | end   | NULL | NULL |           |  3   |   8  | baz-end-2   |
|  3 | end   | NULL | NULL |           |  3   |   9  | baz-end-3   |
+----+-------+------+------+-----------+------+------+-------------+
```

Is there a way to convince mysql to give me a result set like the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
select foo.id as foo_id, foo.foo, bar.id, bar.bid, bar.bar, null, null as baz_bid, null as baz from foo
join bar on foo.id=bar.id
)
union
(
select foo.id as foo_id, foo.foo, null, null, '', baz.id, baz.bid as baz_bid, baz.baz from foo
join baz on foo.id=baz.id
)
order by foo_id asc, bar desc, baz_bid asc
```